# Algorithm for Adams-methods with variable step-size

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, algorithms

I have the following question:
Can you give me an algorithm for the Adams-methods with a variable step-size $h$?

We're trying to approximate $$y(t_{j+k})=y(t_{j-l})+\int_{t_{j-l}}^{t_{j+k}}f(t,y(t))dt$$ using the polynomial interpolation of $$(t_{j-q},f(t_{j-q},u_{j-q})),...,(t_j,f(t_j,u_j)).$$ We use the Newton-form to get:

$$u_{j+k}=u_{j-l}+\sum_{i=0}^{q}c_i[t_{j-i},...,t_j]f$$ with $c_i=\int_a^b\prod_{l=0}^{i-1}(t-t_{j-l})dt.$

I have to write a code that calculates $u_{j+1}$ using the Adams-Bashford/Moulton-method. But I can't figure out how the algorithm would look like. Can someone help me here?

Comment: In cases such as this it is often advantageous to try to solve the problem for one or more small value of the central parameter in this case $q$. Frequently, a pattern emerges and you get a good idea of how the general case behaves. Have you tried to complete the problem for $q \in \{1,2,3\}$?